# How to re-suspend silver from the dried out silver paste?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, materials, solvents

Kindly suggest any method or solvent to re suspend silver from old dried out silver paint/paste. It's a 25 years old "Dotite©" D-550 bottle. Strangely there is no expiry date mentioned on the bottle.

Comment: Generally speaking, with difficulty. After 25 years perhaps it is time to get a new bottle?

Comment: A current advert (https://www.2spi.com/item/05003-ab/) displays the jar labelled *with* expiry date.

Answer (score 5):

According to [SPI Supplies](https://www.2spi.com/item/05003-ab/):

> If the Dotite Silver Paint dries out, unlike some other silver paints, it can be re-suspended with the addition of [SPI #05004 Silver Paint Thinner](http://www.2spi.com/item/z05004/silver-paints-pastes/) followed by an ultrasonic bath treatment.

Generally, ketones are used as diluents, also for conductive paints (acetone, methyl ethyl ketone (MEK), methyl isobutyl ketone (MIBK)).